# Is it possible to embed open transcript in website along with youtube video?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I would like to embed a Youtube video on my website including the open transcript option. Is there any iframe parameter or alternative method available? Also, is it possible to show the video with an open transcript by default on both Youtube and on the website?